# Disable The Function of Drawing on The Desktop (CTRL+CLICK(DRAG))

Tags: shortcut-keys, desktop-environments

I have a problem with the `CTRL+CLICK(DRAG)` in the default Ubuntu desktop.
I can't open a new tab in the browser by `CTRL+CLICK`, but when I press `CTRL` and then drag the pointer there will be a line drew on the desktop. I don't know how to erase it.
I think there's no problem with the browser, this is caused by a service/program in Ubuntu itself. 
You can see this screenshot:
[image]

I only found this on my default Ubuntu desktop. I am not experienced this problem in GNOME Desktop. 
I have installed softwares that I don't know exactly what it does. I think that's why it happen. But I want to know how to disable this, and what is it?

Can I find the settings for this in dconf-editor? How?